# Bash, read variable with variable inside

Tags: bash, variables

I have a script.

```
style_header[true]="background-color: rgb(230,250,230);"
style_header[false]="background-color: rgb(250,230,230);"

if COMMAND; then
    export=true
else
    export=false
fi

echo "${style_header[$export]}"
```

COMMAND finished ok, so export=true, but it returns style_header[false] variable "background-color: rgb(250,230,230);".

```
background-color: rgb(250,230,230);
```

I need to return this.

```
background-color: rgb(230,250,230);
```

It works with number 0 or 1 as index, but I need 'true' or 'false' variable inside.

Is possible to do that? I mean set array index as variable.

Comment: By default, `style_header` is an indexed array, so things like `style_header[true]` are processed by treating the index as an arithmetic expression. Since neither `true` nor `false` is defined as a variable, they both evaluate to 0. So `style_header[true]` and `style_header[false]` are both equivalent to `style_header[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `declare -A style_array` to declare it as an associative array. By default it's assumed to be an indexed array.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A style_header
style_header[true]="background-color: rgb(230,250,230);"
style_header[false]="background-color: rgb(250,230,230);"

if COMMAND; then
export=true
else
export=false
fi

echo "${style_header[$export]}"
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/8kB0Wu)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I tried it with declare before, but I did something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you used `-a` instead of `-A`?

Comment: Yes, it could be the problem. Thanks.